# Postfix not using given ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, postfix-mta

I'm getting errors, such as the one below, in my /var/log/mail.log file.

```
Apr 9 18:28:29 blueberry postfix/smtps/smtpd[13294]: warning: TLS library problem: error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 45:
```

I'm 100% sure the certificates are valid since I'm using them on my websites, all of which couldn't be happier with them. Postfix was also happy previously, but since I renewed the certificates it's been spamming this when my Nextcloud server tries to (and can't) connect to the mail server, despite my mail client still working (although without rDNS as I didn't manage to get my provider to set it up).

I assume the blame is somewhere with Nextcloud - presumably the php handler for mail. Another thing that could be at fault that I tried to check is OpenSSL, but I have no idea how to replace its certificates with my own (generated by Acme.sh).

Both dovecot and postfix have in their config mentioned the correct path to my keys, hence the assumption above.

EDIT: Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out, when I updated my certificate locations when I changed the method of acquiring them (certbot vs acme.sh), I got a typo in one of the filenames. /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf was correct and so was /etc/postfix/main.cf, but /etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map had a typo which I didn't see previously - and so was throwing a certificate error.